# How to tell typeorm that an id is generated on the database using createTable on migration

Tags: typeorm

... I defined this create table.

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
        name: 'categoria',
        columns: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int',
            isPrimary: true,
            generatedIdentity: 'ALWAYS'

        },
        {
            name: 'nome',
            type: 'varchar(100)'
        }
        ,
        {
            name: 'categoria_mercadolivre',
            type: 'varchar(100)'
        }
    ]
    }), true)
}
```

On another migration, I try to insert some data

```
await queryRunner.manager.query(`insert into categoria (nome) values ('eletrônicos');`);
```

But I get this:

> error: null value in column "id" of relation "categoria" violates not-null constraint

Answer (score 0):

I am using Postgres and the correct data type is serial. This  is easy to skip.

```
await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
        name: 'categoria',
        columns: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'serial',
            isPrimary: true,
            generatedIdentity: 'ALWAYS'

        },
        {
            name: 'nome',
            type: 'varchar(100)'
        }
        ,
        {
            name: 'categoria_mercadolivre',
            type: 'varchar(100)'
        }
    ]
    }), true)
```